# Do you have to partition before running mkfs on a single partition disk?

Tags: backup, debian, filesystems, partition, mkfs

I see that some people don't use fdisk to create a partition on /dev/sdb... what is the difference between making and not making a partition for a single partition disk?

I just added a partition on a virtual disk, ran mkfs.ext4 and mounted it, but I just wondered what would have been different if I did not create the partition via fdisk first and just typed mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdb...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mke2fs would tell you that it is an entire device rather than a partition. It is still able to create the filesystem, but you need to confirm that you want to do this.

Is there any specific reason for not using LVM to manage your disks?  It really is easy and gives you a lot of benefit, especially if you need to expand later on.